# Problem with XRDP

Tags: xrdp

[image: connection error]

Hi I have a problem. I am try to fix this after installed xrdp and change port on 5900, but this not solved my problem at all.

Can you help me?

Comment: Hi, you didnt say much about what you have done already, or what software you have tried. Nevertheless this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391164/setting-up-cross-platform-vnc-system/391199#391199) may help you in setting up a 'new' system.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your local machine. You're supposed to use the IP of the machine you're trying to connect to.

Comment: I know, but I done it like in internet tutorials, and doesn't work.
When i change ip adress on 10.0.0.x - real IP address -  it shows "connected" and Remote desktop window is closed